# receive multiple query parameters in method GET API REST NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am trying to receive multiple parameters without knowing which one arrives and which one does not, to filter a GET in the find () method

NODE JAVASCRIPT MONGOOSE

```
app.get('/venta',  async (req, res) =>{
    let a = req.query.anio;
    let f = req.query.fecha;
    let c = req.query.cajas;
    let q = {};
    if(a != undefined) q.anio = a;
    if(f != undefined) q.fecha = f;
    if(c != undefined) q.cajas = c;
    
    Venta.find({$or: [q]}).exec((err,ventas)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            mensaje: 'no se encontro las ventas'
        })
        return res.json({
            ok: true,
            ventas
        })
    });
    
})
```

It occurred to me to put together a "q" list and insert the filters that are reached in the request. $ OR does not work

QUESTION> how can I fill the FIND () method based on the amount of filters that I am receiving in the request

thx

Answer (score 0):

if you want any document that fulfill one of the conditions it needs to be a list of conditions. `[q]` is just an array with one element that contains all the filters with an and conjunction. to have the $or functionality it should be `$or = [{anio:a},{fecha:f},{cajas:c}]` for an arbitary number of filters you can loop on the key value pairs of req.query and insert them in an array accordingly. like in the example shown

Comment: ok but I don't understand how to loop through the req.query and add them to a "Q" array to generate my filter list

Comment: let q = [];
        for (var propName in req.query) {
            if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
                console.log(propName);
                var i={};
                i[propName] = req.query[propName];
                // var i = {propName : req.query[propName]};
                
                q.push(i);
            }
        }
    Venta.find({$or: q}).exec(...                                     My SOLUTION